# who does IndexError: list index out of range appears ? i did some test still cant find out

Tags: python

Im working on a simple project python to practice , im trying to retreive data from file and do some test on a value
in my case i do retreive data as table from a file , and i do test the last value of the table if its true i add the whole line in another file

Here my data

```
 AE300812  AFROUKH  HAMZA  21  admis 
 AE400928  VIEGO  SAN  22  refuse 
 AE400599  IBN KHYAT  mohammed  22  admis 
 B305050  BOUNNEDI  SALEM  39  refuse
```

here my code :

```
fichier = open("concours.txt","r")
fichier2 = open("admis.txt","w")
contenu = fichier.read()
tab = contenu.split()
for i in range(0,len(tab),5):
    if tab[i+4]=="admis":
        fichier2.write(tab[i]+" "+tab[i+1]+" "+tab[i+2]+" "+tab[i+3]+" "+tab[i+4]+" "+"\n")
fichier.close()
```

And here the following error :

```
if tab[i+4]=="admis":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You look at `tab[i+4]`, so you have to make sure you stop the loop before that, e.g. with `range(0, len(tab)-4, 5)`. The `step=5` alone does not guarantee that you have a full "block" of 5 elements left.

Comment: @tobias_k thank u i didn't pay attention to this one , but the problem that stand here is the program add only the first value thats return return , and i dont know how to make it work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look at `tab[i+4]`, so you have to make sure you stop the loop before that, e.g. with `range(0, len(tab)-4, 5)`. The `step=5` alone does not guarantee that you have a full "block" of 5 elements left.

But why does this occur, since each of the lines has 5 elements? They don't! Notice how one line has 6 elements (maybe a double name?), so if you just `read` and then `split`, you will run out of sync with the lines. Better iterate lines, and then split each line individually. Also, the actual separator seems to be either a tab `\t` or double-spaces, not entirely clear from your data. Just `split()` will split at any whitespace.

Something like this (not tested):

```
fichier = open("concours.txt","r")
fichier2 = open("admis.txt","w")
for line in fichier:
    tab = line.strip().split("  ")  # actual separator seems to be tab or double-space
    if tab[4]=="admis":
        fichier2.write(tab[0]+" "+tab[1]+" "+tab[2]+" "+tab[3]+" "+tab[4]+" "+"\n")
```

Depending on what you actually want to do, you might also try this:

```
with open("concours.txt","r") as fichier, open("admis.txt","w") as fichier2:
    for line in fichier:
        if line.strip().endswith("admis"):
            fichier2.write(line)
```

This should just copy the `admis` lines to the second file, with the origial double-space separator.